Moore complex of opposite simplicial set
I have often seen the claim that different conventions for the normalized Moore complex interact in a simple way with taking opposites of the simplicial abelian group at issue.  But I haven't been able to get the signs to work out.  My question is:

How can the normalized Moore complex $N_{*}(A^{\text{op}})$ be realized as a subcomplex of the Moore complex $C_{*}(A)$?

For example, Kerodon (00RA) claims that there is a canonical isomorphism of Moore complexes $\psi : C_{*}(A^{\text{op}}) \to C_{*}(A)$ acting as $\psi_{n}(x) = (-1)^{n}x$.  But I don't see how this could work.  For example, the naturality square for $2 \to 1$ would then require that
$$
d_{0}x - d_{1}x + d_{2}x
=
-
(d_{2-0}x - d_{2-1}x + d_{2-2}x)
=
- d_{0}x + d_{1}x - d_{2}x
$$
which is off by a sign.
The discussion at that Kerodon tag and at Exercise 8.3.4 of Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra suggest that the two usual conventions
$$
N_{n}A = \bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1}\ker d_{i}
\qquad\qquad
\tilde{N}_{n}A = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker d_{i}
$$
for realizing the normalized Moore complex as a subcomplex of the Moore complex $C_{*}A$ should be related by $N_{*}(A^{\text{op}}) \cong \tilde{N}_{*}(A)$, but I can't find an isomorphism that actually makes this work.
